# limiting by an additional LINQ parameter

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following in an MVC application:

```
        var selectedArticles =
            vm.Articles.Except(
                vm.Articles.Where(x => x.Quantity == 0)).ToList();
```

I need to add another parameter. I DONT want to show the articles where the option HideUntilDate != NULL && HideUntilDate > todays date

Any tips?

Comment: Why are you using `.Except()` - it can be just `vm.Articles.Where(x => x.Quantity != 0)`

Comment: `(x => x.Quantity == 0 &&  x.HideUntilDate != .......`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except not needed

```
var selectedArticles = vm.Articles
   .Where(a => a.Quantity == 0 && !(a.HideUntilDate != null && a.HideUntilDate.Value > DateTime.Today));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the requirement logic to your `where` clause's lambda expression

```
 var selectedArticles =
          vm.Articles.Except(
                vm.Articles.Where(
                   x => x.Quantity == 0 || 
                   x.HideUntilDate == null || 
                   x.HideUntilDate < DateTime.Now.Date()
               )
          ).ToList();
```

Comment: tbh, Tim Schmelter's answer is arguable more readable, and certainly more efficient.